# "IIf with In" operator in access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Hello Thanks in advance,

Need a quick help in access query with IIF and IN operator together.

Trying to achieve below mentioned criteria in a query but but not working for this case " In ("Ordered", "Pending")  " however if I put a single value without IN operator then it works.

```
Like IIf([Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]![StatusForSup]=0,IIf(IsNull([Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritOdrStatus]),"*",[Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritOdrStatus]),In ("Ordered", "Pending"))
```

Comment: What is the expression you have at the left of "Like"?

Answer (score 3):

I will assume in this answer that the subject of this condition is ***FieldX***. Just replace it with whatever you have on the left of the ***Like*** operator.

#### The problem

You cannot combine ***Like*** and ***In*** operators like that. If you resolve all the ***IIf*** conditions, the erroneous expression really comes down to this:

```
FieldX Like In ("Ordered", "Pending")
```

...which is invalid syntax. Valid would be either:

```
FieldX Like "Ordered"
```

or:

```
FieldX In ("Ordered", "Pending")
```

#### The Solution

As you want to use different operators on this ***FieldX*** depending on other conditions, you need to express this using multiple WHERE conditions:

```
WHERE  (    [Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]![StatusForSup] = 0 
       AND  FieldX = Nz([Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]![RepCritOdrStatus], FieldX)
       )
  OR   (    Nz([Forms]![ReportCriteriaSelection]![StatusForSup],1) <> 0 
       AND  FieldX IN ("Ordered", "Pending")
       )
```

The above should be equivalent with what you intended to do. I made use of the [***Nz*** function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php).

Comment: Hello his seems to work but there was nothing in left of that function as t was in criteria row however I request you to please provide me you expert comment on below mentioned problem please (as it will be part of this query only):
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169216/iifformcontrolname-1-is-null-in-access-query-criteria